# What would be the best storage opportunity in db with ingredients

Tags: database, storage

Lets say there is 500.000 recipes in a table called "recipes", and I need to store the ingredients for each one of these. Would it then be best to create a new table called "ingredients" or make a column in the "recipes" table, and store a JSON string with the recipes.

What would perform best in case of loading etc.?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how much commonality you have with the ingredients between recipes.  If there are a lot of ingredients in common, even considering measurements and such, then you may save a lot of space by storing them in a separate table. However, that will make your queries slightly more complicated and possibly slow down your database response.

Another thing to consider is storing your ingredients separately will make it faster and easier to select recipes based on ingredients, as you are using indexes as opposed to searching fulltexts.

Comment: So you would suggest to store them in another table, where I have the recipe_id and then just add all the ingredients the user have chosen, with measurements. But lets say that the user has 11 ingredients for his recipe, then it will make 11 rows for that recipe. Is that what you were thinking of?

Comment: I would think rimsky82 suggested to have three tables - recipes, ingredients and their relation. This way you can easily search by ingredients and you don't have duplicate data; so can you later extend your database with some ingredients specific data.